# How to smooth images loaded from server in ActionScript3

Tags: image, actionscript-3, smoothing

I'm trying to smooth an scaled image loaded from another website. The image is not animated. 
It works well if I use a local image. but it seems not work with images loaded from remote server.

Here is the snippet:

```
    ...

    //_loader.load(new URLRequest(http://img.example.com/remote.jpg));
    _loader.load(new URLRequest("../assets/local.jpg"));
    _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

    ...

protected function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var image:Bitmap = Bitmap(event.target.content);
    image.smoothing = true;
    image.pixelSnapping = "never";
}
```

As tested, when I load local.jpg, it works perfect. But when I load remote.jpg from the server, the smoothing param didn't work.

Anyone knows why? 
I searched everywhere, but no one has the same problem. I'm not using Flash Professional, it's a pure ActionScript Project built in Flash Builder. And the image is not animating. So wired...

Comment: Are you doing anything to `image`? Because it is a separate instance and any changes there will not take effect

Comment: @gladoscc `Bitmap(event.target.content)` just returns the image casted to `Bitmap` so the reference is the same as the one in the `Loader` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched day by day, and finally find the answer:

```
    _loader.load( new URLRequest("http:…." , new LoaderContext(true));
```

The most important is the second param of load() method, it's a LoaderContext. Reference:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#load()

Although I set the crossdomain file in the server, without the "new LoaderContext(true)", it won't read the crossdomain file. That's why it doesn't work at first.

If you have the same problem, hope it's helpful to you!

Answer (score 2):

Because you are pulling an image from a remote server you need to set a cross domain policy xml file on the web server where the image is held.

Without this you can't alter bitmaps at a sub pixel level.

Example of:
http://www.senocular.com/pub/adobe/crossdomain/policyfiles.html

More details
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.edu.html

Comment: I have set the crossdomain.xml. I'm wondering it doesn't work because I didn't request this crossdomain.xml file when I pull the image.

Comment: So you have added a crossdomain.xml file on the root of the web server where the image is held and the cross domain file specifies * as the allowed domain? yes? That should be enough to allow bitmapdata modification.